# Java Recursive Constructors

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

I need some basic help. I am very confused. I am trying to create a Fractal Triangle, which basically means that each triangle creates 3 children triangles.

My class is made up of two constructors, a public one and a private one. The point of the public constructor is to create itself, and then create 3 more 'child' triangle objects. (The amount of levels of triangles is based off of the variable depth, so depth 1 just means one big triangle, depth 2 means 1 big triangle and 3 sub triangles etc.)

**I guess my big question is how do I recursively call the private constructor again so it can use itself as a parent?**

Here is a link to an animation of what I am trying to create ( just the triangles) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Tq6mYckE93clFZRnVIMHZBZms/view?usp=sharing

Also: _parent.makeTriangle( points[0], points[1]) creates a 'ATriangle' and returns it.. if you were wondering what that was for.

```
    public FractalTriangle( int depth, ATriangle tri, int height )
   {
      this(tri,null,depth);

      // set up values of instance variables
      _depth    = 1;
      _p2height = height;
      _parent = null;
      _tri = tri;

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // Set the triangle's color to a value that depends
      // on its depth.
      //
      // Generate the children triangles for this root.
      // Make sure your code for this is as clean and
      // modular as possible.
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      if( depth > 1 )
      {
         trianglelist = new Vector<FractalTriangle>();
         Point points[] = tri.getPoints();
         FractalTriangle f1 = new FractalTriangle( _parent.makeTriangle( points[0], points[1]), this, depth-1 );
         FractalTriangle f2 = new FractalTriangle( _parent.makeTriangle( points[1], points[2]), this, depth-1 );
         FractalTriangle f3 = new FractalTriangle( _parent.makeTriangle( points[2], points[0]), this, depth-1 );
         trianglelist.add( f1 );
         trianglelist.add( f2 );
         trianglelist.add( f3 );
      }

   }
   /**
    * recursive constructor; it's private, so can only be called from methods
    * of this class. It will get called by the public FractalTriangle.
    */
   private FractalTriangle ( ATriangle tri, FractalTriangle parent, int depth )
   {
_parent = parent;
      _depth = depth;
      _tri = tri;
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // get parent's height from parent parameter to compute this height
      //
      // save other parameters in instance variables
      //
      // recursively create children -- only if recursion depth limit hasn't
      // been reached and the minimum height test passes
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      if( depth > 1 )
      {
         trianglelist = new Vector<FractalTriangle>();
         Point points[] = tri.getPoints();
         FractalTriangle f1 = new FractalTriangle( this.makeTriangle( points[0], points[1]), this, depth-1 );
         FractalTriangle f2 = new FractalTriangle( this.makeTriangle( points[1], points[2]), this, depth-1 );
         FractalTriangle f3 = new FractalTriangle( this.makeTriangle( points[2], points[0]), this, depth-1 );
         trianglelist.add( f1 );
         trianglelist.add( f2 );
         trianglelist.add( f3 );
      }

   }
```

Comment: The first line of your public constructor `this(tri,null,depth);` seems like maybe it's a bug. Since your public constructor looks like it does all the necessary setup.

Comment: You've done it. What's the question?

Comment: Yeah I guess that is an error.

Comment: @EJP the code doses not create any childs in the private constructor, theres some sort of error

Comment: 'Some sort of error' is not a problem description. If there is a compiler error message, or exception thrown at runtime, you need to include that information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

That would be an unnecessarily complicated solution. It can be solved with a simple Tree in java.
You cannot invoke a private constructor in java. You have to have a static method that can be called without instantiating a class which returns an instance of the class. Private constructors are useful only in singleton design patterns. But that wouldn't solve your problem.
http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

If you still want to go this route here is an example.
[What is the possible benefit (if any) of allowing recursive constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594940/what-is-the-possible-benefit-if-any-of-allowing-recursive-contructors)

Your code will work recursively even without a private constructor. But if you want to use a private constructor, this is the only way you can call a private constructor recursively.

```
    {
    ...
    FractalTriangle f1 = FractalTriangle.createFractalTriangle( _parent.makeTriangle( points[0], points[1]), this, depth-1 );
    ...
   }

   public static FractalTriangle  createFractalTriangle(ATriangle tri, FractalTriangle parent, int depth ){
           return  new FractalTriangle( _parent.makeTriangle( points[0], points[1]), this, depth-1 );
    }
```

Create a static method that returns an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two constructors why not do something like:

```
public FractalTriangle ( ATriangle tri, FractalTriangle parent, int depth, int height, int numberOfChild )
   {
      if(null != parent){
          _parent = parent;
          _p2height = height;
          _depth = depth;
        }else{
          depth =1;
          _parent= null;
        }
      _tri = tri;
      ...
      for(int i=0; i < numberOfChild; i++){
            FractalTriangle child = new FractalTriangle(tri, this, 3, 0, 0);
      }
   }
```

To Call:

```
   FractalTriangle parent = new FractalTriangle(tri, null, 1, 1, 3);
```

Comment: I am sure that would be ideal, unfotunatly I am required by my professors to do it the way he has it set up

Comment: so the method signatures are fixed? ie public and private constructors?

Comment: Also: _parent.makeTriangle( points[0], points[1]) creates a 'ATriangle' and returns it - this part shouldn't be the triangles in trianglelist be the child triangles instead? I believe that is what your professor wants, you create child inside the parent, cause you are creating child and not assigning it anywhere then creating 3 triangles inside parent from a different method

Comment: What do you mean by not assigning it anywhere?

Comment: I meant it is redundant, this constructor is called assigned a few variables and it is repeated in public method ie, _tri variable. also recursive constructors doesn't necessary need to be public private, if your assignment is recursive constructors, repeatedly calling public method is still recursive, as per my example posted